# 50-400 bps consciousness: why do we draw the line there?

Tags: human-biology, brain

I have found studies that suggest the human consciousness can process 50 to 400 bps.  The exact number varies, but it's always quite small.  It is usually associated with some test results, but how do they decide where to draw the line?  How do they argue their test is the right one?  Is there some strong knee in the curve, or maybe a brainwave being detected which we recognize as occuring with conscious thoughts but not unconscious thought?

Comment: You'll have to read the individual papers. Personally I find these not to be very useful or meaningful measures. Brains aren't computers, they don't process bits.

Comment: Stating generalizations about consciousness is crazy because, while the conscious mind can process a small amount, the brain has like an L2 cache, a secondary level of consciousness that is immediately available if necessary... Consider you senses can record 2-3 megabytes per second of sound, image, and other information. secondary subconcious processes make that data available to the conscious process if necessary, and it's more about what we choose to ignore than what we have the power to focus on. we have a vast amount to data which is nearly in focus and available for deliberate thought.

Comment: The brain also has culture, so the 400kb of concious thought is built on a previous library of 10gb of best reactions for a given time, it's like a processor that builds itself, so a guy playing tennis or driving a car, processes huge amounts of previously concious thought automatically.

Comment: For the benefit of many if not most readers could you add at least a bit of background of what bps is and how it applies to human consciousness, if not some evidence of prior research beyond the unsupported "I have found studies..." *Thanks!*